# From immutability's concern, any issue with this code (call by reference)

Tags: java

From immutability's point of view, is there any concerns for this code ?

```
public class mainPkg {
    private boolean MyFunc1(MyInfo info) {
        List<MyObj> myList = new ArrayList<MyObj>();

        anotherPkg.MyFunc2(info, myList);
        anotherPkg.MyFunc3(info, myList);

        return CollectionUtils.isEmpty(myList);
    }
}

public class anotherPkg {
    public static boolean MyFunc2(MyInfo info, List<MyObj> myList) {
        if(info.version < 2) {
            myList.add(new MyObj('wrong version'));
            return false;
         }
         return true;
    }
}
```

MyFunc1(), MyFunc2() are used only in 1 place, and will only be used in this place. When i pass list as argument into myFunc2, it's like the classic call by reference. Not using global variable for myFunc1().

From immutability's point of view, what're are the concerns for this code ?

Comment: Immutability doesn't have a "point of view". Are you saying that someone doesn't like the way you're passing around a `ArrayList` instance and mutating it in different places? If so, then -- why not ask that person?

Comment: ppl won't give me a clear reason, other than books like "clean code", "clean architecture" said so.

Answer (score 1):

You are mutating the list referenced by `myList` in `MyFunc2`, therefore, your code is not immutable, therefore, it doesn't make sense to look at concerns "from immutability's point of view".

Comment: When ppl insists on the immutable way, there has to be a good reason. But i just don't see any good reason to do the immutable way here, that's my question.

Comment: Immutability is one of the basic ways means to aid thread safety. If you can't change an object, then multiple threads will see the same data. Obviously, not everything can be immutable, utilise this when I can.